# How does weak cartesian morphisms in the arrow category coincides with pullbacks in the original?

Tags: category-theory

Background: for a functor $p:E\to C$, a *weak cartesian* morphism $f\in E(a, b)$ is a morphism that $\forall f'\in E(a', b)$ such that $p(f')=p(f)$, there exists a unique morphism $g\in E(a', a)$ such that $f'=fg$ and $p(g)=\rm id$. I've made a [diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsMyxbMCwxLCJhIl0sWzEsMSwiYSciXSxbMCwwLCJiIl0sWzAsMiwiZiJdLFsxLDIsImYnIiwyXSxbMSwwLCJnIiwwLHsic3R5bGUiOnsiYm9keSI6eyJuYW1lIjoiZGFzaGVkIn19fV1d) for your convenience.

Bart Jacobs said in *Categorical Logic and Type Theory* that for the codomain functor $cod:C^\to \to C$, pullbacks in $C$ coincide with cartesian morphisms in $C^\to$, with proofs left as exercise. I was trying to prove this. I started by $f\in C^\to(b, a)$ a pullback diagram and $f'\in C^\to(b', a)$, where $a, a', b$ are morphisms in $C$ and obviously $cod(f)=a=cod(f')$. Then I'm stuck. [This diagram](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNixbMSwyLCJBIixbMjQwLDYwLDUwLDFdXSxbMSwxLCJCIixbMTIwLDYwLDMzLDFdXSxbMCwyLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFswLDEsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzAsMCwiXFxidWxsZXQiXSxbMSwwLCJCJyIsWzMzNyw2MCw0NCwxXV0sWzEsMF0sWzIsMCwiYSIsMix7ImNvbG91ciI6WzI0MCw2MCw1MF19LFsyNDAsNjAsNTAsMV1dLFszLDIsIiIsMix7InN0eWxlIjp7ImJvZHkiOnsibmFtZSI6ImRhc2hlZCJ9fX1dLFszLDEsImIiLDAseyJjb2xvdXIiOlsxMjAsNjAsMzNdfSxbMTIwLDYwLDMzLDFdXSxbNCw1LCJiJyIsMCx7ImNvbG91ciI6WzMzNyw2MCw0NF19LFszMzcsNjAsNDQsMV1dLFszLDAsIiIsMSx7InN0eWxlIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJjb3JuZXIifX1dLFs1LDAsIiIsMCx7ImN1cnZlIjotMn1dLFs0LDIsIiIsMix7ImN1cnZlIjoyfV1d) has what I've gathered so far. I'm stuck on the step where you need to come up with a morphism $o\in C(B', B)$. I know how to do the rest -- just apply the universal property of pullbacks. But how can I find $o$? Or did I misunderstood some definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just write the definition carefully and you will get precisely the definition of a pullback. $f$ that you start with is a commutative square with sides $a$ and $b$. You also have an arrow $a'$ mapping to $b$ with the same codomain as $a$ and the same map from this codomain and the codomain of $b$. [Here is a picture](https://q.uiver.app/?q=WzAsNSxbMSwwLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFsyLDAsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzEsMSwiXFxidWxsZXQiXSxbMiwxLCJcXGJ1bGxldCJdLFswLDIsIlxcYnVsbGV0Il0sWzAsMSwiYiJdLFsyLDMsImEiXSxbMiwwXSxbMywxXSxbNCwyLCIiLDEseyJzdHlsZSI6eyJib2R5Ijp7Im5hbWUiOiJkb3R0ZWQifX19XSxbNCwzLCJhJyIsMV0sWzQsMF0sWzEwLDUsImYnIiwwLHsiY3VydmUiOi0xLCJzaG9ydGVuIjp7InNvdXJjZSI6MTAsInRhcmdldCI6MTB9LCJjb2xvdXIiOlsyNDAsNjAsNjBdfSxbMjQwLDYwLDYwLDFdXSxbNiw1LCJmIiwyLHsic2hvcnRlbiI6eyJzb3VyY2UiOjIwLCJ0YXJnZXQiOjIwfSwiY29sb3VyIjpbMjQwLDYwLDYwXX0sWzI0MCw2MCw2MCwxXV1d). But now both the definition of a weak cartesian map and of a pullback assert the dashed arrow exists and is unique.

Comment: I missed the part where the codomains must meet. Thanks very much!